# surround.vim: deleting embedded ruby tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim, erb, macvim, surround

Using surround.vim, while in an .html.erb file, if I type ysw= in front of 'text' it will correctly give me <%= text %>.

However, if I move the cursor over 'text' and type ds=, it doesn't delete anything, which if I'm reading the docs correctly, it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, it actually sounds like you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/18).

If it is a big issue / time sensitive, you could ask Tim for a bit of guidance on the rewrite he mentions and attempt it yourself.

Other than that, I think you're out of luck! The only thing you can do is wait until Tim implements it himself.